# Generate div automatically by mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to create a system to issue opinions on a given thing. I'm at a good point, but I can not get created for each element taken from the database a correspond div. Let me explain, for example if I have three reviews made by the three authors, I would like three divs for the reviews, and three for the authors, then automatically generated by the loop. How can i do?

Comment: I do not get your question properly... Do you want to display $Feedback,$UserNick and $UserMail inside html div tag?

Comment: Hi, no, I want that for every element taken from the database is automatically created a div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this.. First of all add `<body>` tag to your html document

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <?php

      $Content = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM feedback");

        while($Row = mysql_fetch_array($Content)) {

        $Feedback = $Row['FeedbackUser'];
        $UserNick = $Row['UserNickname'];
        $UserMail = $Row['UserEmail'];

echo "<div>{$Feedback}</div>"; // Displaying feedback as div
echo "<div>{$UserNick }</div>"; // Displaying UserNick as div
echo "<div>{$UserMail }</div>"; // Displaying UserMail as div 


  }
?>
</body>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for